# Error Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView

Tags: android

I am retrieving data from a table student(name,result)
Using the following code:

```
public class SelectActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    TextView tv_select;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select);

        tv_select =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_select);
         new LoadAllStudents().execute();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_select, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class LoadAllStudents extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SelectActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(pDialog!=null)
            {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                pDialog =null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

           // List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(app_url);
            String studString ="";

            try {
                JSONArray student = json.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i= 0;i<student.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject json1 =null;
                    try
                    {
                        json1 = student.getJSONObject(i);
                        studString = studString+
                        "Name"+ json1.getString("name")+"\n"+"Result"+json1.getString("result")+"\n";

                    }catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
tv_select.setText(studString);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

It fails giving the following error:

```
SelectActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41914d60 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.shubham.helloworld.SelectActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41914d60 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:218)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
            at com.example.shubham.helloworld.SelectActivity$LoadAllStudents.onPreExecute(SelectActivity.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            at com.example.shubham.helloworld.SelectActivity.onCreate(SelectActivity.java:35)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Added code highlighting and fixed spelling

Comment: This usually happens when the activity is put in the background or finished while trying to show the Dialog. Do you happen to call this task from somewhere else or is it being put in the background somehow? You could fix it by closing the dialog in `onPause()` or setting cancelable to false. @Mark there's a place in the edits to comment what you fixed, just in case you didn't realize it